# What would be an optimal control to use in order to collect an expiry date for a card (not credit) on iOS (iPad)

Tags: ios, controls, ipad, datetimepicker

I need to ask a user to fill in the expiry date for a card. The default spinners on iOS for a date picker doesn't provide a simple month/year option and the pods I've found are terrible.  I would create my own, or provide PRs to fix up the AP:I of the controls, but I'm constrained by time.

That said, I'd really like to know if the spinner is even the most correct/optimal control to use of this on iOS. I've considered validated text fields, but still think the spinner is probably the best.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could simply [**scan the card**](http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/auto-fill-credit-card-forms-using-your-iphones-camera-ios-8-0157364/) in iOS8+.

As for *optimal*, I think it will depend on testing. As someone that uses an iPad for almost anything, I'd say "use a spinner". However, a quick research shows that both spinner and text inputs are user almost equally, with a slight preference for text inputs. See samples below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So, it seems that other than **card scanning**, you'll need to decide based on testing.

## Additional Resources

Mastercard seems to favor text inputs on **[Simplify iOS docs](https://www.simplify.com/commerce/docs/sdk/ios)** and you can take a look to **[4 Tips to Improve Your Credit Card Form UX](https://www.usertesting.com/blog/2015/09/16/credit-card-ux/)** for some ideas

Comment: Sounds like there's no clear winner. The scanner idea sounds interesting, but since my thing isn't actually a credit card, I'm not sure it would work. It is interesting that they seem to generally separate the selectors for month and year into district controls. That might be a better idea than the month/year combined spinner.

Comment: ah yes, if you go with a spinner it should be separated, that goes without saying

Comment: So something like this is a faux pas: https://github.com/nairteashop/NTMonthYearPicker ?

Comment: no, because it has 2 separate inputs despite its presentation. however, making a clear distinction between months and year is the tested and commonly accepted way to do it (as you'll see from the examples)